# Scraping multiple webpages with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib, time
class scrape(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.urls = ['https://www.onthemarket.com/for-sale/property/wigan/', 'https://www.onthemarket.com/for-sale/property/wigan/?page=1', 'https://www.onthemarket.com/for-sale/property/wigan/?page=2', 'https://www.onthemarket.com/for-sale/property/wigan/?page=3', 'https://www.onthemarket.com/for-sale/property/wigan/?page=4', 'https://www.onthemarket.com/for-sale/property/wigan/?page=6']
        self.telephones = []
    def extract_info(self):
        for link in self.urls:
            data = urllib.request.urlopen(link).read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
            for tel in soup.findAll("span", {"class":"call"}):
                self.telephones.append(tel.text.strip())
            time.sleep(1)
        return self.telephones

to = scrape()
print(to.extract_info())
```

What is wrong? This code is hanging after second website. It should extract phone numbers from each webpage in list `self.urls`

Comment: If you are getting any error please post it as well

Comment: I've tried your code, everything works fine. [Finished in 9.3s]

Comment: There is no error. python shell is doing work, but not returning anything. I use Spyder with Python 3.6. I am waiting more than 5 min and happens nothing.

Comment: Are you sure that it is not a network problem? Is url that is being processed accessible at the moment on hanging?

Comment: ventik, yes a network problem is possible, but in my case first two sites are scraped correctly, but after that is hanging without a reason. ventik what python IDE have you used?

Comment: @FootAdministration I checked your script in cmd. Save it to file and then execute from command line. I've checked several times in a row and it works fine.

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ (and __scraper__, __scraping__, __scraped__) not scrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is put a `headers` in your request parameter and make a go. Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, time

class scrape(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.urls = ['https://www.onthemarket.com/for-sale/property/wigan/', 'https://www.onthemarket.com/for-sale/property/wigan/?page=1', 'https://www.onthemarket.com/for-sale/property/wigan/?page=2', 'https://www.onthemarket.com/for-sale/property/wigan/?page=3', 'https://www.onthemarket.com/for-sale/property/wigan/?page=4', 'https://www.onthemarket.com/for-sale/property/wigan/?page=6']
        self.telephones = []

    def extract_info(self):
        for link in self.urls:
            data = requests.get(link,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}) #it should do the trick
            soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, "lxml")
            for tel in soup.find_all("span",{"class":"call"}):
                self.telephones.append(tel.text.strip())
            time.sleep(1)
        return self.telephones

crawl = scrape()
print(crawl.extract_info())
```

Comment: Btw, in your case you found two sites working and the rest are not but in my case what i was having is a blank list. However, after putting headers in the request parameter, I got it working flawlessly @FootAdministration.

Comment: Thank you Shahin it worked for me! Great answer! Have a nice day!